# Multitasking and applicationWillEnterForeground

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to have my app reload data when it is brought to the foreground via the applicationWillEnterForeground method. I can get the function to work and write to the NSLog, but I have a function that I want to be called from another class, how would I go about this?

I have tried below:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //Re-run...
    [MainViewController reRun];
}
```

Be gentle bit of a newbie...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can register to UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, and reload your data when your receive it.

Comment: Hi Benj, thanks for the response. Could you give me a nudge in the right direction on this?

Comment: in Your ViewController : [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
Then create a method named -(void)appEnterForeground:(NSNotification*)notif in which you do what you want to reload your data.